# Merging two arrays in ascending order (both arrays are same size)

Tags: c++, arrays, merge

My friend and I are struggling with a merging function.  It requires that both arrays have the same size, thus the merged array twice the number.  This is what we have so far:

```
void mergeTwoSortedArrays(const int a1[], const int a2[], int mergedArray[], int n) 
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while (i <= n && j <= n) 
    {
        if (a1[i] == a2[j]) 
        {
            mergedArray[k] = a1[i];
            mergedArray[k] = a2[j];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
}
```

It's not working however.  Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Is this for merge sort or something?  The usual approach is to do the combined merge, much like you have done already, followed by a copy.  Here's the first part.  You were a little confused.  Read through this and you'll see it makes sense:

```
while (i < n && j < n) {
    if (a1[i] <= a2[j]) {
        mergedArray[k++] = a1[i++];
    } else {
        mergedArray[k++] = a2[j++];
    }
}
```

Then you handle the remaining elements.  Obviously the loop finishes when only one array reaches the end.  So now you need two much simpler loops.  Only one will execute - no need for complicated tests:

```
while (i < n) mergedArray[k++] = a1[i++];
while (j < n) mergedArray[k++] = a2[j++];
```

I turned your tests into `<` instead of `<=`, because the arrays are zero-based.

Comment: +1 this is nearly identical to the algorithm I always use for merge-lists, with only the closer being different (I use `if (i<n) copy-a1-side else copy-a2-side`, which is identical to this, less one boolean eval). Nice answer, sir.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with -

```
void mergeTwoSortedArrays(const int a1[], const int a2[], int mergedArray[], int n) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    // Iterate and compare two input arrays until at least one of them reaches to boundary. 
    while (i < n && j < n) {
        if (a1[i] < a2[j]) {
            mergedArray[k++] = a1[i++];
        }
        else if (a1[i] > a2[j]) {
            mergedArray[k++] = a2[j++];
        }
        else if (a1[i] == a2[j]) {
            mergedArray[k++] = a1[i++];
            mergedArray[k++] = a2[j++];
        }
    }

    // Copy the remaining items from the other array, without comparison until, boundary.
    while (i < n) mergedArray[k++] = a1[i++];
    while (j < n) mergedArray[k++] = a2[j++];

}
```

Comment: Ashok, we have something close to your:

void mergeTwoSortedArrays(const int a1[], const int a2[], int mergedArray[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (i < n && j < n)
    {
        if (a1[i] <= a2[j])
        {
            mergedArray[k++] = a1[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            mergedArray[k++] = a2[j++];
        }
        if (j == n)
        {
            mergedArray[k++] = a1[i++];
        }
        if (i == n)
        {
            mergedArray[k++] = a2[j++];
        }
        
    }
}

It's not giving us the right output. Any help with this?

Comment: Try these arrays:

int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5}
int b[] = {1,2,3,3,3}

It returns {1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,0,1}.

We think it goes through the first three elements in a, then it goes through all of b, and it count j up to 5, and then it doesn't know how to deal with a since there is no sixth element in b[].

What did we do wrong?

Comment: @khguru13 you missed the copy operations that follow the merge.  Did you not read my answer?  Or this one, for that matter.

Comment: @khguru13 but if I try {1,2,3,4} and {9,7,6,5}, then instead of coming {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9}it is coming{1,2,3,4,9,7,6,5}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're trying to merge them as in interleave them or just concatenate two distinct arrays. If it's striding:

```
#include <iostream>

void mergeTwoArraysIntoOne(const int* lhs, const int* rhs, int* dst, size_t numElements) {
    const int* const endLhs = lhs + numElements;
    const int* const endRhs = rhs + numElements;
    for ( ; lhs < endLhs ; ) {
        while (rhs < endRhs && *rhs < *lhs)
            *(dst++) = *(rhs++);
        *(dst++) = *(lhs++);
    }
    while (rhs < endRhs)
        *(dst++) = *(rhs++);
}

void dumpArray(int* array, size_t elements) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < elements; ++i)
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int array1[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int array2[] = { 10, 20, 30 };
    int array3[] = { 1, 11, 31 };

    int result[6];

    mergeTwoArraysIntoOne(array1, array2, result, 3);
    dumpArray(result, 6);

    mergeTwoArraysIntoOne(array2, array1, result, 3);
    dumpArray(result, 6);

    mergeTwoArraysIntoOne(array1, array3, result, 3);
    dumpArray(result, 6);

    mergeTwoArraysIntoOne(array3, array1, result, 3);
    dumpArray(result, 6);

    mergeTwoArraysIntoOne(array2, array3, result, 3);
    dumpArray(result, 6);

    mergeTwoArraysIntoOne(array3, array2, result, 3);
    dumpArray(result, 6);

    return 0;
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/7ODqWD

If it's just concatenating them:

```
std::copy(&lhs[0], &lhs[numElements], &dst[0]);
std::copy(&rhs[0], &rhs[numElements], &dst[numElements]);
```